# Modify NLog configurations specified with Configuration API through NLog config file xml

Tags: c#, nlog, nlog-configuration

I have a project which uses the below code to create a NLog instance.

```
 public FileTarget CreateNLogFileTarget(string layout, FileArchivePeriod archiveMode, int maxArchiveFiles, 
        bool keepFileOpen, bool enableConcurrentWrites, ArchiveNumberingMode archiveNumberingMode, string fileName)
    {
        FileTarget fileTarget = new FileTarget();
        fileTarget.Layout = layout;
        fileTarget.ArchiveEvery = archiveMode;
        fileTarget.MaxArchiveFiles = maxArchiveFiles;
        fileTarget.KeepFileOpen = keepFileOpen;
        fileTarget.ConcurrentWrites = enableConcurrentWrites;
        fileTarget.ArchiveNumbering = archiveNumberingMode;
        fileTarget.FileName = fileName;

        return fileTarget;
    }

    FileTarget infoLogFileTarget = CreateNLogFileTarget(@"${longdate} ${message}",
            FileArchivePeriod.Hour, 70, false, true, ArchiveNumberingMode.Rolling, "${basedir}/Logs/" + infoLogName + "/${shortdate}{#}.log");
```

I am using this project in another project and I need to use this NLog utility class to create my loggers. But I need to override these configurations. How can I override these configurations through the xml file? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `FileTarget` from `CreateNLogFileTarget` in your XML config, you should first find out the target name of the `FileTarget` it's probably in other parts of the code. Then you could use the target in your config:

`<logger name='*' minlevel="Trace" writeTo='theTarget' />`

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear mate. This is what is already done in the library project from which I am using the logger. I cannot access the LogManager instance or any of the code from it. I need to do this through the XML file. Because there is no modify access to this code. Its coming from a library!

Comment: Ah missed that! Will change the answer.

Comment: Is this the line you are talking about? nLogConfiguration.AddTarget(infoLogName, infoLogFileTarget);

Comment: And what I need to do is, override all those configurations that have been done through the code. Such as maxArchiveFiles, archiveEvery etc. Is that possible through this suggested approach?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by using NLog-variables. Change your CreateNLogFileTarget to setup the parameters to get their value from NLog-variables.

Then on startup check if these NLog variables already exists in the loaded NLog-configuration. If not then they are set by the runtime, before calling CreateNLogFileTarget.

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables